How to conditionally update variable as I iterate through a dataframe?
I would like to have the following code work:
buy_price=0
def tradeStrategy(row):
    #entry conditions
    if buy_price==0 and row['ema200'] < row['ema50']:
        buy_price = row['close']
        
    #exit conditions
    if buy_price > 0 and row['ADX_14']<20 or (row['ADX_14']>20 and row['DMP_14']<row['DMN_14']) or row['ema200'] > row['ema50'] :
        sell_price = row['close']
        profit = sell_price-buy_price
        buy_price=0
        return profit
btc_1m_2023['tradeStrategy'] = btc_1m_2023.apply(tradeStrategy, axis=1)

buy price needs to be updated only if the above conditions are met. If I make a global variable buy_price within my function and then set buy_price = 0 it will obviously be updated to zero each time the function is called - which is not what I want. How can I write something where buy_price is only updated when my if statement conditions are met?

Both of the buy_price assignments are dependent on if statements, so buy_price is only updated when the conditions are met.  I don't understand what else you are asking for.

If I understand correctly that you want a global value for buy_price that is updated only when specific condition is met then just add global buy_price to the top of your function so that the function updates the global value rather than the local variable.

I don't understand what this code is supposed to do exactly, and I'm not sure why you're certain that "[buy_price] will obviously be updated to zero each time the function is called", since the "exit conditions" need to be met for that, no? Please make a reproducible pandas example including some example data, desired output, and actual output. You are using Pandas, right? Please add the tag for it.

Oh, I just realized this is ambiguous: "make a global variable buy_price within my function and then set buy_price = 0". Are you saying you tried setting buy_price = 0 unconditionally? Please show the actual code. I thought you meant the buy_price = 0 inside the "exit conditions" block.

@NotAName I think I did a poor job explaining my issue, but yes, your solution solved my problem. I thought I had already tried your suggestion but something must have escaped my attention!
